# Command line for ./configure - Debian/Red Hat packages

Tags: debian, openssh, packages, configure

I want to configure and compile openssh server from source. Can I check command line how it was configured in current Debian and/or Red Hat packages? I'd rather not lose any features or badly set up path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debian repository is available in Debian repository and you should be able to find out the configure parameters there. They are listed in the [`debian/rules`](https://anonscm.debian.org/git/pkg-ssh/openssh.git/tree/debian/rules#n64) file and collected in `confflags` variable.

Latest Fedora builds `openssh` with flags that can be found in the Fedora dist-git.  Namely the [`openssh.spec`](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/rpms/openssh.git/tree/openssh.spec#n553) file is the important one.